# Multilines Label in ListView becomes SingleLine after scrolling the ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a multiline Label in a ListView. The label can display multiline texts when the ListView is rendered. but after scrolling the ListView and going back to the Multilines Label, the label becomes SingleLine, the words are wrapped.

I am not sure if it's a bug or not. Does anyone have same issue?

btw, I used CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" in the ListView to get all items.

Comment: Xamarin Forms version 3.5 by any chance?

Comment: Would you post a demo with your rendered listview so that we can test it for you?

Comment: Updating Xamarin.Forms to 3.5.0.169047 fixed the issue. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#recycleelement) `RecycleElement` caching strategy is recommended for use:

> .. it is generally the preferred choice, and should be used in the
>   following circumstances:
>
> - When each cell is **largely similar**, with the cell template unchanging.
>     ..

Multiline label since to break these circumstances. Sadly you will have to disable the caching strategy if you want the `ListView` to behave normally on both iOS and Android. Alternatively, you could try to replace the `ListView` by a [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) or an experimental [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).

Answer (score 0):

i understand there are issues with the recycleElement & caching strategies.
how about you use a custom view (equivalent to multiline Label)  and use that as a viewcell, you can be creative with this according to your requirements

```
Ref: https://adityadeshpandeadi.wordpress.com/2018/07/15/the-more-interactive-listview/
```

I have written a blog about list view interactions, however you can just pick the viewcell code. :)